# Фильтрация массива по датам

Tags: javascript

У меня собирается массив из календаря, то есть когда я нажимаю на календаре на дату, то она заносится в массив и выходит такой массив ['дата от', 'дата до'], потом у меня есть еще один массив который берет данные с excel, в нем первый элемент это дата, и мне нужно как-то фильтровать этот массив чтобы там были данные от такой даты - до такой даты

[image: ['06.10', 321, 45600, 0.7039473684210527, 34567, 45600, 23, 45600, 0.5, 4234, 4234, 4311, 3245, 422, 23, 34532, 77685, 4234, 4234, 4311, 3245, 422, 23]] Вот массив с данными

[image: ['2022-06-01', '2022-06-30']] и вот массив с началом даты и концом

Нужно вывести массив с данными между этими датами

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Почему нет указания года в первом массиве? Что если придёт `['2020-06-01', '2022-06-30']`? Как узнать что надо отсеивать?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript может распознать текущую дату из строки вроде "2022-10-2":

```js
const date = new Date("2022-10-2") // Всё ок.
```

Из этого можно получить временную метку:

```js
const timestamp = date.getTime();
```

Она в свою очередь легко поддается манипуляциям.

Я точно не знаю строки в каких форматах распорзнаются для получения текущей даты. Однако даже если у Вас есть только месяц и день, можно преобразовать это в строку похожую на ту, которая выше: `год-месяц-день`
Например:

```js
let label = "06.10";
label = [ "2022", ...label.split(".").reverse() ]
  .join("-"); // "2022-10-06"

const date = new Date(label);
```

Надеюсь, с тем, чтобы отфильтровать массив временных меток, проблем у Вас не возникнет

**Изменено:**
new Date() поддерживает такой формат: `"06.04.2022"`, что очень удобно. Но всё-равно меняет день и месяц местами (6 месяц, 4 день). Будьте с этим осторожны)